# How to interpret normalized predictor in logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, standardization

I have this data that I think I'll need to standardize. The problem is that the person who gave me the data didn't initially tell me that they are measured with in different units. When I looked at the distribution and other plots, they looked way to suspicious. So, I asked the question if the data contains two measurement from two different units. The person is checking to see if it indeed has measured in different units, and will possible send me the conversion (if there is one for labs - depending on the assay used to calculate). The units, if different, are measured in `ng/L` or `ng/mL`.  So, until then, I decided to standardize the data using `scale` function in R. Then I ran `Simple Logistic Regression` on it, I get the following results.

**NOTE:** I was told I can't simply convert `ng/mL` to `ng/L` or vice-versa.

```
   Var         |     coef   | odds.ratio  |  CI               |  p.value
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    X1         |   0.3475169| 1.42         |(0.2152,0.4799)    |    0.00 **
```

How can I interpret this result from standardized predictor values?

Comment: If you don't know the original units, how could you possibly interpret the coefficient?  And what do those six numbers mean?  (We could guess, but it's far better to be explicit.)

Comment: My apology. I inadvertently forgot to add those vital pieces of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken. `scale` only makes sense if you know which units are measured in per-mL and which are measured in per-L. The sample mean and standard deviation make no sense, so why would `(X-mean)/sd` make sense? If you knew the units, you could convert them to a common scale by multiplying or dividing by 1,000 anyway. You need to wait for the correct units to be confirmed for each observation by the lab.